# How can I create a function that passes a variable which I can later address to

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Similar execution is in javascript addEventListener('event', function(e){});
What I try to understand is that how can I create a similar result where "e" variable holds an object.
I have some understanding so far, is this right?

```
var some = function (node, func) {
func(node);
}
```

and the node is that variable I try to achieve

Comment: yes I think this is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `e` variable is an abbreviation of the keyword `event`. This is passed to every function called upon via `addEventListener` as the last argument. `e` is an event object which contains references to the type of the event fired and the event parent (and many other event specific properties).

But that is not your question. You ask if you can pass an object to a function:

```
var some = function (node, func) {
    func(node);
}
```

In short yes. In your example the function `some` takes two arguments. The first can be everything: *string, number, function, element (node)* etc. The second argument needs to be a function object. Since you try to invoke within the `some`-function. You then pass the `node` object to that function.

Also everything in JavaScript is an object.

Working example:

```js
some = function(node, func)
{
  if (typeof(func) != undefined && {}.toString.call(func) === '[object Function]') //test if object exists and is a function.
  {
    return func.bind(node);
  }
}

function alertIt(node)
{
  alert(node.textContent);
}


//event setter
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", some(document.querySelector("div"), alertIt), false);
```

```html
<div>Hello world!</div>
<button>Click to activate</button>
```